# Is it possible to load multiple angular4 apps under the same url?

Tags: angular

I have 3 angular4 apps. I want to load app1 as basically the splash page app so when you go to www.myurl.com then you come to app1. From that splash page the user is presented with 2 button options. Clicking button1 leads to app2 and clicking button2 leads to app3. To make things more complicated I would like app2 to load under the exact same url as app 1 but then have app2 load under www.myurl.com/admin. I have attached an image of how this works. My question is. Is this possible with angular4? I could not find any sources that explain how to do this, so any thoughts on how to do this would be really appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Could you make them all one app, just different modules? Angular modules are set up to exactly do this.

Comment: All said before  + routing ?

Comment: Ok, the reason that I thought about doing it like this is because app2 will receive 95% of the traffic and has about a 10% the amount of code as app2. So I thought it might better to have separate apps so 95% of the users aren't downloading a whole bunch of app that they won't use. Do you still think have the apps as different modules is a better way to go?

Comment: Modules can do that. You can download modules in a lazy loaded fashion, so only the modules that a user uses are downloaded.

Comment: Ok wow that is sweet. I will look into lazy loading modules then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can make them all one app, just different Angular modules, then you can use lazy loading.

You can find out more on lazy loading here: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-6-asynchronous-routing